# DotNetOpenAuth OAuth2 Ignore https certificate issues or use http

Tags: https, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I am working with access to an api with access control using Oauth2. I use DotNetOpenAuth

```
server.AuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri("https://api.xxxxxx.com/oauth/authorize"); 
var client = new DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.WebServerClient(server, client_id, client_secret);
client.GetClientAccessToken();
```

Which results in..

```
AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

They have certificate errors, that won't be solved before....well...before the project is actually released, but I need to work on it now.....

DotNetOpenAuth will not allow the auth. url without HTTP

How can I make the code either accept the invalid certificate OR make DotNetOpenAuth accept a HTTP auth. url?

I have tried fiddling with the web.config settings, and to see if the trick with a "forgiving" servicePointManager could be used, but I don't know where to attach that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it... in web.config:

```
  <dotNetOpenAuth>
        <messaging relaxSslRequirements="true"/>
```

This made it ignore the fact that the provider of the webservice had an invalid certificate on their test server